# How Habitable are these Planets?

Tags: planets, moons, habitability

For the book I'm writing for my world, Damarian, the villains of the series (The NUSA, America's descendant) are banished off Damarian (Spoilers). The banished are shipped off, but 3 groups formed, based on where they wanted to go. One group wanted to go to Zolou (A new planet, .29 AU from Kenser), another to Meq (A water world .38 AU from Kenser), and a third, smaller group to Ahki (The largest moon of Checuti after Damarian, the size of Mars). The groups split up and go to each planet (Or moon, for Team Ahki).

Using my other question abut where Damarian should orbit Kenser, the above AU measurements for Zolou and Meq are within the Earth-like radiation level belt.

***Here are the parameters for these three:***

Zolou: 75% Earth's Gravity, and 90% Earth's diameter, but 125% Earth's atmospheric pressure (125% Earth's atmospheric thickness). Climate is hot and humid.

Meq: Roughly Earth's gravity, diameter, and pressure. Cold and dry globally.

Ahki: Roughly Mars gravity and size (3.721 m/second squared), about Earth's atmospheric pressure, and hot and dry world-wide.

By habitable, I mean, would they be able to support these atmospheres and be survivable for humans?

UPDATE: All aforementioned bodies have a magnetic field, Zolou and Meq due to tectonics and iron cores, Ahki due to a magnetic fluid which I am calling Amosite. Amosite has a melting point far above the boiling point of water, but about the same as Earth's mantle. It flows under the crust, and forms a magnetic field.

In addition, the climates I provided above are relative to Earth. There are dry areas of Zolou and wet regions of the other two, but Zolou is generally hotter and wetter than Earth, Meq is colder and dryer in general, and Ahki is dryer and hotter on average. Zolou and Ahki's poles are pretty nippy, but are not like Earth's poles. Meq's equator is colder than Earth's equator, and the poles are *much* colder than the poles on Earth.

For specifics, Zolou is 5-8 degrees Celsius hotter than Earth, Meq is 6-8 degrees Celsius colder, and Ahki is 6-9 degrees Celsius hotter. These are all average differences between a location on Earth and the matching location on each planet.

Humidity wise, Zolou has an average of 65% humidity, Meq has 25% humidity on average, and Ahki has 15% humidity on average.

Comment: Qs like this always surprise me. It's your universe and you set the rules, so the answer is always "yes" unless you're specifically asking from the point of view of the real universe. In that case, you can't have 75% gravity and 125% atmospheric pressure because gravity is a big cause of atmospheric pressure. Mars is considered within the Goldilocks Zone, so that one's OK, but global climates are unrealistic (even on Mars). On a planetary scale, cold-and-dry is a lot easier to obtain than hot-and-humid, but there's more (much more) to habitability than you've provided. (\*continued\*)

Comment: Which begs the question, how important is it to be scientifically perfect?

Comment: We need information about the star, primarily. But you could say more about the atmosphere of each of this planets/moon too.

Comment: @JBH Venus has 95%G and 3500% atmospheric pressure, so you can really tweak gravity and atmospheric pressure to whatever values you want... but not with a breathable atmosphere. There is much more to inhabitability than gravity and pressure. Chemical composition. Radiation levels. Temperature. A million details more.

Comment: @Rekesoft You're certainly correct, but the OP's requirement that the planets be habitable removes planets like Venus from the mix. Atmospheric pressure can be increased by increasing water vapor or dust... but that reduces habitability. However, we're in 100% agreement that a lot of details are missing to effectively judge the habitability of the planets from a scientific perspective. I'm hoping we'll hear from The Darke Lorde soon.

Comment: @JBH Raises the question, not begs.

Comment: @rek [Read this](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/beg-the-question) and remember that grammar correction is the least valuable use of comments. If you want to be that nit-picky, spend time on [ell.se] or [english.se].

Answer (score 1):

You are not giving enough information for anyone to correctly answer that question but I'll do my best with what you gave me.

**So, Zolou** seems perfectly habitable to me at first glance. An atmosphere that's just 25% thicker than Earth's is not a big deal at all and if its composition is similar to that of Earth, it's probably also perfectly breathable too (because the amount of oxygen and other molecules in the atmosphere is actually very important and crucial). The hot and humid climate might be kind of a problem though, if it's comparable to something like the climate you would encounter at Earth's Ecuator in summer in the Amazone... Keep and eye, because hot, humid climates are very dangerous and way more dangerous and hard to survive long term than dry and hot climates because our sweat turns totally useless at cooling us down because of the hot humidity. If we are talking about very humid 30-40°C that's quite a dangerous climate to deal with because without the ability to cool down, you can easily start suffering tachycardia, high blood pressure and eventually die from a heat stroke.

**Now Meq**... That's way too little information to work with, like, it might or might not be habitable depending on a lot of factors like how cold, how dry, atmospheric composition, etc. But assuming it is just moderately cold and moderately dry in general, It might be an habitable place for humans to settle on as far as you don't go way to far from the equator since the poles would be way too cold considering the planet as a whole is moderately cold.

**About Ahki,** it would need to be quite a young planet and have a huge iron core to sustain a magnetic field that can protect the planet's atmosphere from solar radiation. So, assuming that's the case and that its atmosphere is breathable and stable, It should be totally habitable even if it's hotter than Zolou since it's dry and that makes things much easier for the reason I mentioned before when talking about Zolou. Keep in mind that it must have some water somewhere, at least subterranean for it to be considered habitable

Comment: Ahki formed very similarly to Damarian, in that it has a magnetic fluid that flows under the crust, and thus has its own magnetic field.

Comment: Zolou could be habitable only at the poles while the equator could be a wet furnace.

Answer (score -2):

### The (obvious) answer

No offense but you already answered your own question by having three factions that you explicitly named and distinguished, then you sent them to three isolated places that you also explicitly named and worked out in vivid detail, as an author it makes no sense for you to just have any particular faction reach their destination and drop dead on the spot because there was no way for them to adapt to the environment they encountered there, no matter what kind of environment it could be.

There are countless articles, speculations and fiction about what kind of technology could be applied to pretty much any celestial body if we'd want to live on one, not to mention there are also a plethora of authors on numerous platforms that addressed this issue in their own way. I would personally suggest checking out "KURZGESAGT - IN A NUTSHELL" Youtube channel, I found some of their videos quite inspiring.

Comment: Your "obvious answer" is useless and misses the point completely. Your post basically boils down to; "you're the God of your story, so if you decide the planets are habitable, then they're habitable". That's an assumption however. What if they aren't entirely the God of their story? What if certain elements, like the laws of physics, aren't fully in OP's control? As in, they want their story to be scientifically correct to some degree, meaning they can't just state xyz about their planets, and then decide that they're habitable. They need to know if, scientifically, xyz allows for life.